# How to set the static IP address and change the Host Name of a FreeBSD machine?

Tags: networking, microsoft-virtual-pc, freebsd, static-ip, hostname

I have a FreeBSD machine running as a Virtual Machine. There are 2 things that I need to do.

1. Change the IP Address and Host name
2. Put this machine into the Network. My machine is already connected to the Network.
   I need to configure my FreeBSD machine to be accessed by my Host machine.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Edit `/etc/rc.conf` and change the settings for [the hostname](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/configtuning-core-configuration.html) and [interface IP address](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/config-network-setup.html) - you'll need to reboot afterwards
2. That depends on whether you're running a DNS server for your LAN or not.  If you are, simply add it to your DNS zone.  If you aren't you'll need to add it to the hosts file of all other systems.  Detailed instructions require further information.

The [FreeBSD Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/) is a good source of basic FreeBSD knowledge.

Comment: and `man rc.conf`